# NullPointer on changing color of Spinner text

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-spinner

I have an Activity with 4 tabs.
In some tab i have a `Spinner`, which i change text color via this piece of code:

```
mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            //((TextView)parentView.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.rgb(249, 249, 249));
            ((TextView) parentView.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            //DO NOTHING
        }
    });
```

The first time i display the Spinner everything goes as expected: the text change color and become black. Then i proceed to change tab several times and, after 2 or 3 changes, i get NullPointerException on

```
((TextView) parentView.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

and I can't figure out why.

I've already tried to use a boolean variable like

```
if(!alreadyChangedColor)
    ((TextView) parentView.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

but it changes color only the first time I show the Spinner and after i change tab the text go back to its original color.

**EDIT**

I'm using default spinner (the only thing i change is the blue line).

Spinner in XML:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/paymentMethodValue"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/paymentMethodText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ibanValue"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ibanValue"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/paymentMethodText"
    android:entries="@array/arrayPaymentMethods"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:textSize="12pt" />
```

This are the entries I use:

```
<string-array name="arrayPaymentMethods">
    <item>Ri. Ba. 30gg</item>
    <item>Ri. Ba. 60gg</item>
    <item>Ri. Ba. 90gg</item>
    <item>Bonifico Bancario</item>
</string-array>
```

This is the Adapter I use along the spinner:

```
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) container.findViewById(R.id.mySpinnerValue);
ArrayAdapter mySpinnerAdapter = (ArrayAdapter) mySpinner.getAdapter();
```

**EDIT/2**

I think I've found a solution:

Use a variable to keep the `selectedView` the first time I create the activity and then use that variable in `onItemSelectedListener`.

Here some code:

```
private View _selectedItemView;
mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        if (selectedItemView != null){
            _selectedItemView = selectedItemView;
            ((TextView) selectedItemView).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        } else {
            ((TextView) _selectedItemView).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps someone else than me!

Comment: `selectedItemView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)` doesn't exist.

Comment: `((TextView)selectedItemView).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);`

Comment: Have you tried checking if getChildAt(0) is null before making the color change? I haven't done this in awhile but I think I had a similar issue and onItemSelected was getting called before any items were listed.

Comment: @JaredRummler: the first time I call `onItemSelectedListener` `parentView.getChildAt(0)` (the same as (`selectedView`) has some values, but when I call it the second time, it gives me a null reference.

Comment: debug and see, what causes it.

Comment: I think that the problem is the `ItemSelectedListener`. The first time I load spinner's elements i do an "itemSelected" event, but the second time not...

Answer (score 0):

```
      private TextView _selectedItemView;
      mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                   _selectedItemView= (TextView) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                   _selectedItemView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
```